# Java Diferencia entra una Excepción y un Error

Tags: java

Que tal comunidad estaba terminando una aplicación y pasó una pregunta por mi cabeza..

Cual es la diferencia entre una excepción y un error en java, espero puedan aclarar esta pregunta.

La información con la que me he topado hasta ahora es que extienden de `java.lang.Throwable` pero son diferentes en la manera de representarse en la consola o aplicación

Answer (score 4):

- **`Error`** : son a menudo `fatal` en la naturaleza y la recuperación de error no es posible, lo que es diferente en el caso de excepción que no puede ser fatal en todos los casos.
- **`Excepción`** se divide generalmente en dos categorías por ejemplo marcada y sin marcar.

`Excepción marcada` : Tiene lugar especial en el lenguaje de programación Java y requiere un intento de captura obligatoria por último bloque de código para manejarlo. Ejemplo `FileNotFoundException` `TimeoutException`

`excepción no Marcada` , que son subclase de [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)  su mayoría representan los errores de programación. La mayoría ejemplo común de excepción no comprobada es `NullPointerException` en Java .

> el error son fatales en la naturaleza y la recuperación puede no ser posible, por otra parte, por la cuidadosa manipulación de excepciones  puede hacer el código más robusto y protector frente a diferentes escenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno la diferencia es simple:

**Error:** *Se refiere a errores graves en la máquina virtual de Java, como por 
  ejemplo fallos al enlazar con alguna librería. Normalmente en los programas 
  Java no se tratarán este tipo de errores.*

**Exception:** *Representa errores que no son críticos y por lo tanto pueden ser 
    tratados y continuar la ejecución de la aplicación. La mayoría de los 
    programas Java utilizan estas excepciones para el tratamiento de los errores 
    que puedan ocurrir durante la ejecución del código.*